# Is it possible to defend my program whilst offline?

Tags: c#, windows, postgresql, security

I need to find a way to block user access to my database that will be installed in his pc.

So, here on the company we have a problem. We need to block user access to our database that will be installed on their pc, what I mean by this is...

We have 2 softwares. A web App ERP and an instalable finances App.

We reached the conclusion that it was unnecessary to have 2 standalone apps, and that we should put the finances app inside our ERP.

But this comes with a problem, theres a big part of our users that don't trust the web, and web apps, they think that what is on their pc is what is 
safe, and is where it should be.

We don't want to maintain the 2 standalone softwares needlessly.
We asked our users if they'd be happy with a progressive web app, their answer was the same.

Then we tried to make a way to run our ERP on their pc whilst offline, as an executable, but that comes with a lot of troubles, we need to install IIS, PostgreSQL, .net frameworks, pgadmin, our metadata database (which it shouldn't be accessible in any way shape or form by the user!), etc... that lets our app run on the users pc.

Of course we don't want to do that, but we got no choice left. We need to at least block our metadata database from being accessed, since the whole structure of the web app is there and we don't want to share it with the competition

Our solution was installing all that was needed inside a virtual drive and run the app from there. but all the files and databases are available to the user for him to mess with.

How can we restrict acess to that virtual drive the best possible, and protect our intelligence property? is it even feasable? I've run out of ideas and don't know what else to do, so any help is welcome.

Should I take another route or is it a lost cause?

Comment: If your users complain that web app is not good for them and if you believe that they are surely wrong, you can trick them by creating something like a web view inside your local UWP software that does nothing but loading a page and of course you can define some exceptions like in order to use this software you need to be connected to the Internet bla bla bla

Comment: You cannot protect your IP by handing them your entire code, database scheme, etc. They can easily copy and whitelabel it now that they have the whole structure. Furthermore, it is very unsecure as an intruder or hacker who gets access to a PC has an easy job to do!

Comment: We know and that's why we don't want to do that, thats our problem

Comment: We wish our users, would let us to that, bit they complain that they should be able to use the software fully ofline...

Comment: So use the solution in my first comment. It will take few lines of code only in Xamarin.Forms to create a WebView that loads the remote ERP. Rule out the offline option! They will still think that it is a local software installed (which actually is) but inside of it is a Web Browser controller that loads your web app inside.

Comment: If data is accessible to an offline app, it is accessible period. You can futz around with encryption or obfuscation, but you're essentially trying to have DRM. You can put up roadblocks for insufficiently determined attackers, but you can't guard against sufficiently dedicated ones. Basically, you have a decision to make about what you fear more: people stealing your IP, or too many customers walking away. You can't have your cake and eat it too. (You could try the legal route so you can sue the pants off anyone who abuses your trust, but that's a bit out of scope for this site.)

Comment: The other solution that comes to my mind is deploying a secure VM on their local network so they can access the ERP when they don't have an active Internet connection.

Comment: we even thought about sending them a docker container, but not all users would be able to use it, bcs of docker needs hyper-v as do vms, and when not hyper-v it needs virtualization

Comment: @jeroenMostert I get that, we get that, but I wanted to at least try and see if it existed a solution to do it, thank you all for your time

Comment: The best solution, from a social POV, is to make your *service* irreplaceable, rather than your software, so that a competitor who tries to replicate what you do using just your "metadata" doesn't actually gain a serious advantage, because that's not what your customers depend on. Of course, whether that's possible (and how) depends a lot on your business, and is out of scope for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever has control of the database machine has control of the database. So if the database is running on the client's machine, there is no way to keep an administrative user out of the database.

So if the users don't trust a web application, they will have to trust their system administrators (or themselves, if they have administrator rights to their machines).